# "I have travelled with my friends to Europe and Asia."

Tags: prepositions

I have an issue with the following sentence:

> I have travelled with my friends to Europe and Asia.

Do I have to add 'to' before 'Asia'? I am confused because in spoken English I quite often hear people say the sentence without 'to' before 'Asia'. However, I have learned to put 'to' before Asia. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, “to Europe and Asia” means a trip to both, whereas “to Europe and to Asia” means a trip to one and a separate trip to the other. (Or several such trips.)

However, nobody will actually interpret it that way, especially when spoken. We will assume an unspecified number of trips to either or both; that sort of ambiguity is okay when the listener can ask for clarification.